# Compare SQL Server database with MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, validation, mysql-workbench, database-migration

I have migrated my existing SQL server database to MySQL server database using MySQL workbench Migration Wizard. Because these are two different database servers, I want to ensure there is no data loss along with `stored procedures`, `triggers`, and `views`, I mean everything is intact. I tried using the MySQL workbench `Compare Schema` wizard but that only works for two MySQL databases. Please suggest a way to achieve it.

Comment: You can be sure there *will* be loss - MySQL doesn't support all the features and types, query operators and functions that SQL Server does. Even the concept of "schema" is different. In MySQL it's a synonym for database. In SQL Server it's part of a database. You'll have to match types, sizes and handle the differences

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos is there any way I can list all those differences?

Comment: There is absolsutly no common code between MySQL and MS SQL Server. Collations differs that will results in differences for simple SELECT statements. Datatypes differs and will not deliver the same accurency in computational results. And of course the procedural language is compleltly different between MySQL and SQL Server and it will results syntax errors that won't create such objects (procedure, triggers, user functions). Also MySQL as a lot of functionnality lacks, like temporal tables, XML processing, spatials methods...

Comment: You could test by outcomes ie if you run daily weekly monthly and annual reports you can be reasonably sure that the migration was successful.

Comment: Adapt the test suite you had for the old database.  (You had such, correct?)

Comment: Be cautious of "similar" things that are not identical:  TOP 10 vs LIMIT 10; Sequences vs AUTO_INCREMENT; etc.  The _effect_ may be the same, but the _specifics_ may be different -- _possible_ example: gaps in AUTO_INC that did not exist in SEQUENCE.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-overview-supported.html: "Generally speaking, only table information and its data are automatically converted to MySQL. Code objects such as views, stored procedures, and triggers, are not. But supported RDBMS products will be retrieved and displayed in the wizard. You can then manually convert them, or save them for converting at a later time. "

Comment: Out of curiosity, **why** did you migrate from SQL Server to MySQL? And **what version** of MySQL did you target?

Answer (score 0):

First you should compare database schemas between SQL Server and MySQL to see if there is difference.

I don't think that field are missing, but perharps it needs data type adjustments, index adjestments, etc.

Second, once you fix database schema, you should verify imported datas, including:

- total row number for each tables
- Row contents

For both, the best is to write a verification script (PHP, node.js, python, etc.) that will list all tables of SQL Server, and for each table check row number, identity counter and then datas itself.

Answer (score 0):

- For moving or copying the MS SQL database table's schema into MySQL, you must map data types, find NULL constraint, and determine the field that is set as a PRIMARY KEY.
- This procedure does not support conversion of indexes, foreign keys, identity columns, unique or other table constraints, and character set.
- MySQL supports all the important MS SQL data types. However, there are some SQL server data types that do not match with MySQL data types. Some of the major data types you’ll need to map MySQL with are as follows:

| SQL Server | MySQL |
| --- | --- |
| VARCHAR(max) | LONGTEXT |
| SQL_VARIANT | BLOB |
| IDENTITY | AUTO_INCREMENT |
| AUTO_INCREMENT | TEXT CHARACTER SET UTF8 |
| SMALLDATETIME | DATETIME |
| DATETIMEOFFSET | TIMESTAMP |
| MONEY | DECIMAL(19,4) |
| UNIQUEIDENTIFIER | BINARY(16) |
| SYSNAME | CHAR(256) |

- Organizations may develop the need to migrate from MS SQL server to MySQL because of its rich feature-set, cross-platform and open source availability, and lower cost.
- While migration from one database to another can be performed manually, it can be an extremely time-consuming and error-prone process.
- A better alternative is to use specialized database converter software like Stellar Converter for Database, which is specially designed to help DBAs and developers automate the process of converting a database file format to another. The software converts table records and attributes from MS SQL to MySQL database quickly, while preserving database integrity.